# Trying to return True False values from an "in" statement

Tags: python

I am building a sequence to append a list based on the Boolean values of the output from this excerpt,
but every time I run the sequence it only returns as True and will not append to the list.

```
yesvalues = ["yes", "Yes", "yeah", "ok", "okay"]

spcharacter = (input("Are special Charaters required?: "))
if spcharacter.lower() in yesvalues:
    spcharacter == True
else:
    spcharacter == False

if spcharacter == True:
    useableoptions.append(special)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaking `==` (comparison) for `=` (assignment), so the variable is never set to be anything but a string from `input()` and no string is `== True`.

Besides that, you can just assign directly.

```
yesvalues = {"yes", "Yes", "yeah", "ok", "okay"}

spcharacter = input("Are special Charaters required?: ")
spcharacter = spcharacter.lower() in yesvalues
if spcharacter:
    useableoptions.append(special)
```

Or, shorter, dont use boolean variables

```
if spcharacter.lower() in yesvalues:
    useableoptions.append(special)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was thinking == referred to an equal to and not comparing the items.

Comment: It does mean "is equal to". Think of `=` as "is **assigned** the value of"